# jquery unwanted double quotes in optgroup after adding option

Tags: jquery, csv

I load data from csv and split it to rows and than cells. In my csv file first cell in each row should be my optgroup and the rest should be options within current optgroup. Its working well with only optgroups (one loop), but when Im adding options Im getting extra double quotes in optgroup text and its not displayed. Pls help

```
//loading file
   $.get("file.csv",function(data)

//spliting data
    {
        var rows=data.split("\n");
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
            var cells=rows[i].split(";");

//first cell in the row = optgroup
            $('select').append("<optgroup>"+cells[0]);

//second loop - the rest of cells in the row = options
            for (var j=1; j<cells.length; j++)
                {
                    $('select optgroup').eq(i).append('<option>'+cells[j])
                }
         }
     });
```

Comment: close your tags when you have text in them. Also `<optgroup>` doesn't accept text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the tags properly since you are adding elements this way. Also `optgroup` doesn't have text content. Add that to label.

```
//loading file
$.get("file.csv", function(data)
  //spliting data
  {
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cells = rows[i].split(";");

      //first cell in the row = optgroup
      $('select').append("<optgroup label='" + cells[0] + "'></optgroup>");

      //second loop - the rest of cells in the row = options
      for (var j = 1; j < cells.length; j++) {
        $('select optgroup').eq(i).append('<option>' + cells[j] + '</option>')
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: optgroup doesn't have text content

Comment: @charlietfl took care of that. Updated answer.

Comment: Adding label helped. Thank you guys!